# pthread_exit() is reached before pthread_join call

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, uclibc

Having this piece of code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* PrintHello(void* data){

        printf("Hello from new thread\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int rc;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    T_DATA data;

    Data = init_data();
    rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)data);
    if(rc){
        printf("\n ERROR: return code from pthread_create is %d \n", rc);
        exit(1);
    }
    sleep(100);
    printf("\n Created new thread (%d) ... \n", thread_id);
    pthread_join(thread_id);
}
```

When `main` creates the new thread and then perform `sleep(100)`, the new thread probably reach `pthread_exit` before `main` reach `pthread_join`. Anyways the new thread waits and his resources are not freed until `main` perform `pthread_join` so if i execute `ps` command i will see the new thread during next 100 seconds, am i right?. I would get the same behavior if I use `pthread_detach` instead `pthread_join`? I wonder what happen when the new thread perform the `pthread_exit` before main perform `pthread_detach` over the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread cannot be cleaned up until it terminates, of course. But it also cannot be cleaned up until it is either joined or detached. A thread that terminates without being detached will keep enough information around to allow another thread to join it.

Comment: So the new thread remains being showed when i execute `ps` until main perform `pthread_exit` or `pthread_detach` and after that ceases to exist so it would not be shown again by the command `ps` right?

Comment: @user2119381 I suspect so, but it's an implementation detail. How threads are shown, if at all, outside the process is not something you should rely on.